# Open-source text editor written in Qt

Tags: open-source, text-editor, qt

Is there a good text editor that is written in Qt? For example, for Gtk there is gEdit, Geany, and probably others. But I don't know any such editor written in Qt.

Please note, though, that I'm not asking about demo programs that took 2 days to write, that's not an equivalent to Notepad++ or gEdit.

Also, no KDE apps, I know KDE is based on Qt, but I'm interested in pure Qt applications. Otherwise Kate would be a candidate, it's a solid text-editor.

I want to be able to tweak the source code, so the source must be available.

Comment: Not sure as I didn't check: but with LXDE moving to Qt, maybe Leafpad (which is LXDE's editor) would be a candidate? The latest [official version](http://tarot.freeshell.org/leafpad/) is still GTK+, though, as [LXQt](http://lxqt.org/) is still "in the makes". And Leafpad rather minimalistic (no match for Notepad++ that is ;)

Comment: Since answers should not be lists, but this might interest you nonetheless: http://qt-apps.org/?xcontentmode=4241

Comment: @Gallaecio Thanks, I'll take a look. You should sort them by most downloaded, though - http://qt-apps.org/index.php?xsortmode=down&page=0&xcontentmode=4241. Seems JuffEd is most downloaded there.

Comment: [here](https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php?title=List_of_Qt_Applications#Text_Editors) is a list

Answer (score 4):

what difference does it make? it's just a text editor, most of them are few MB big, I don't expect QT apps to be more lightweight than the apps out there, that being said, and since most Linux distro have GTK in them, I don't understand why a QT notepad would even matter.

I understand some users not wanting to install KDE apps on gnome desktop because it will install many dependencies. But wanting QT apps just because they are QT apps, I don't understand that, certainly not to something as simple as notepad.

Having said that, take a  look at [TEA editor](http://tea-editor.sourceforge.net/), they say that they offer two versions, a GTK version and a QT version, I quote

> TEA is a text editor that provides a wide range of text-processing
>   functions (over 100) and the syntax highlighting. There are two
>   branches of TEA: Qt-based and GTK-based.

That's all I know about it, you can find more on the [about](http://tea-editor.sourceforge.net/#about) page. I never tried it and not interested in doing so. However the project seems inactive, their last release was in 2013. But it looks like a mature project, and it is okay if it's inactive, it's just a text editor, no rocket science, no need to update it so often.

Very few project match Notepad++ or even better, Gedit, sublime text, vim and emacs. Maybe texmate. All the other projects are not even close and no developers interested in reinventing the wheel unless there's a need to, something i don't see. And there's no money in making text editors. Few donations at best.

Comment: The reason is it would look native on both Windows and Linux. All gtk editors are Linux-only, Notepad++ is Windows only. Well, you could run Notepad++ under Wine, and it won't look native, and gtk most certainly doesn't look native on Windows.

Comment: @sashoalm then try http://www.sublimetext.com/

Comment: @Fischer Sublime Text is proprietary.

Comment: @DmitryAlexandrov i know, i was answering his comment, not his question, sublime looks the same on all OS, so it's the one to use if you want same design on all platforms, it's not open source and it has nothing to do with QT so it's not an answer to the original question

Answer (score 3):

[TEA](https://tea.ourproject.org/) is what you are looking for. It is a pure Qt, non-KDE text editor that runs on Linux and Windows.

I do not think that TEA is still in development, but compiled code should still run on newer systems and the code should still compile against newer software versions.

Answer (score 2):

I can not resist suggesting **[qvim](https://bitbucket.org/equalsraf/vim-qt/wiki/Home)**, which is full-fledged gvim ported to Qt.

It is, of course, not a demo program that took two days to write; and it is accompanied by a pool of addons accumulated over twenty years... it goes far beyond Notepad++ or gEdit.

Answer (score 0):

**Kwrite** and **Kate** are my favorites.

TEA has a rather bad interface, Featherpad an odd behaviour when pasting a file path: opens the file in the text editor (maybe that can be changed, but I haven't used it anymore.)